# PHP regex: find the first occurrence of a given pattern in a string

Tags: php, regex

my string can be

```
new-york-10036
```

or

```
chicago-55036
```

the desired result is

```
new-york
chicago
```

and i basically want to remove all the string that come after the first dash - followed by a number

seems easy but i don't know how

Comment: Have you tried starting with some attempts or pseudo code?

Comment: This one should be enough `(.*)-\d+` https://regex101.com/r/mY6fW3/2

Comment: You already have a good start with this: *"i basically want to remove all the string that come after the first dash - followed by a number"* now you can try to put it into a more general pseudo regex, like: `[Anything]-number(s)`, which you then can try to translate step by step into a regex like: `(.*)-\d+`

Comment: pretty sure this would work with preg_match_all: /([a-zA-Z\-]+)\-[0-9]+/g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Negative Lookahead, like so:

```
(.+)(?=\-\d)
```

The regex reads: "get me everything that is **not** followed by exactly one dash and exactly one number after that".

Given the input `new-york-10036` the regex is going to capture only `new-york`. In PHP you can get the matched string with:

```
$string = 'new-york-10036';

$regex = '/(.+)(?=\-\d)/';

preg_match($regex, $string, $return);

echo $return[0] . "\n";
```

It outputs `new-york`.

See the regex working [here](https://regex101.com/r/mY6fW3/1).

Comment: does the "d" stands for number?

Comment: @Francesco actually, it's the `\d`, which stands for "a number between 0 and 9". It's the same as `[0-9]` and is called a "character class", which you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).

Comment: @Francesco Yes, `\d == [0-9]`, but you can probably better remember it with **d**igit

Comment: @Francesco `preg_match` !== `preg_match_all`

Comment: my question was about PHP: given the regex, how do i extract the string?

Comment: ok I got i! preg_match_all("/(.+)(?=\-\d)/", $string, $matches); THEN echo $matches[0][0] THANKSSSS

Comment: @Francesco indeed, I misinterpreted your question. I edited it and believe that it's correct now.